# Validate the form in below input box and send mail using smtp code but page getting refresh

Tags: php, html, forms, email

i am trying to send mail using smtp server but not getting need help below is my form

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <form action="" id="formid" method="post" class="indexform">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_name" placeholder="Name" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="m_number" placeholder="Contact Number" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="organization" placeholder="Organization" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="designation" placeholder="Designation" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tech" placeholder="Technologies" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="requirement" rows="8" placeholder="Describe your Training Requirement Here"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

i want to display validate message below and validation each fields, and send mail when click submit button.

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate the form, you can use **jQuery Validation Plugin**

[Tutorial for jQuery Validation on Form](https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/)

It provides the knowledge from scratch on how to implement the validation on server side.
Hope it helps!